# How can I open multiple webpages when radio button is clicked using only javascript one in new window and other in same tab

Tags: javascript

Am trying to open multiple webpages when a radio button is clicked one should be opened in seperate window and other should be opened in the tab.

Here is my code

```
<li>
  <label>
    <input name="game" type="radio"  class="input slide-action"    
      id="popunder1_1" onclick="myFunction()">
    <span>Look</span>
  </label>
</li>
```

script is:

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_blank",        
   "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=400,height=400");
}
```

I am able to open a webpage in new window but how can I open a webpage in new window and the web page on the tab where the radio button is present at a same time

Regards
Vikas

Comment: after window.open, location.replace('your_url');

Comment: both answers is right. replace is redirect, href is direct navigation as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_blank",        
"toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=400,height=400");
window.location.replace('YOUR_URL');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Append `location.href =` to your function. With `location.href` you can navigate to specific URL in the active "frame":

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=400,height=400");
    location.href = 'http://www.google.ch';
}
```